# get XML from server by URL in AsyncTask and return response to UI

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I try to get xml from server in async task, but my doInBackground method returns me NULL. Where is my mistake? And how I can send result to UI?

[Here is all classes](https://github.com/mrabaev48/Currency)

I have this code for getting xml from server:

```
package classes;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Mikhail on 28.03.2015.
 */
public class GetXMLFromServer {

    InputStreamReader reader;

    public GetXMLFromServer(){
        //reader = null;
    }

    public InputStreamReader getReaderWithXML(String url){

        GetXMlTask task = new GetXMlTask();
        task.execute(url);

        return reader;
    }

    public void setReader(InputStreamReader newReader){
        this.reader = newReader;
    }


    class GetXMlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, InputStreamReader>{


        @Override
        protected InputStreamReader doInBackground(String... params) {
            InputStreamReader iStream = null;
            try {
                iStream = new InputStreamReader(getUrlData(params[0]));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return iStream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStreamReader inputStreamReader) {
            super.onPostExecute(inputStreamReader);
            setReader(inputStreamReader);
        }

        public InputStream getUrlData(String urlString) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet method = new HttpGet(String.valueOf(new URL(urlString)));
            HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
            StatusLine status = res.getStatusLine();
            if (status.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                Log.d("APP", "HTTP error.Invalid server status code: " + res.getStatusLine());
            }
            return res.getEntity().getContent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good example how to use async task [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
Please check it!

The returning is in onPostExecute method.

To send the result to UI use OnPostExecute do call a static method of your UI class.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     YourUIFragmentORActivity.showResult(result);
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

Comment: I've seen it, but I still do not understand how to send result to UI. Your example just show how use AsyncTask inside Activity class.

Comment: In your activity class put your UI variables like global variables. Make your initialization in onCreateView and access them in showresult method.

Comment: Thank you) I'll tyry it)

Comment: https://github.com/mrabaev48/CurrencyVer3/tree/master/CurrencyVer3/app/src/main/java
Look here)

Comment: It's usefull? if yes please aproove the answer and vote them.Tks